# How to escape this JavaScript variable in PHP

Tags: php, javascript, html

With PHP echo I want to get this in the browser:

```
var x = "<td><a class=\"button3\"><input type=\"text\" name=\"" + a + "_" + y + "\" id=\"something\" value=\"\" class=\"inputText\"></a></td>";
```

How to escape this in PHP ?

Comment: you could always just place it in a text file and read the file into a variable in PHP. Or you could take the time to escape all of the special characters properly according to the PHP spec.

Comment: See PHP's `json_encode()` function.

Comment: I don't want to use a PHP variable in JavaScript, I just want to echo a JavaScript line.

Comment: how would you escape the special characters ?

Answer (score 2):

You do not seem to be using single quotes `'` so wrapping your line of code in a string is quite easy when using single quotes.

To *literally show* the text in your browser, you can use the [`htmlentities()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php) function and `echo` it to output it to the browser:

```
echo htmlentities('var x = "<td><a class=\"button3\"><input type=\"text\" name=\"" + a + "_" + y + "\" id=\"something\" value=\"\" class=\"inputText\"></a></td>";');
```

It will convert all characters that are used in HTML to create tags. For example `<` is converted to `&lt;` so it displays the correct character. Please take a look at the [available flags](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php) and select the ones you require for properly displaying your line of code.

Comment: No this doesn't work, after var x = there appears a col. Look here http://bit.ly/WT4xzi

Comment: Your resulting code is full of `<br>`, you need to use `echo "\n";` for newlines. After replacing (some of) them with newlines, you code looks ok to me... I do not know what you mean by ' *after var x = there appears a **col** .* '.

Comment: There is no difference between using echo "\n"; and echo "<br>";

Comment: Do you get the same like this http://bit.ly/VhPjcQ ? I don't want to get the col after var x =" I just want to get     var x = "<td><a class=\"button3\"><input type=\"text\" name=\"" + a + "_" + y + "\" id=\"something\" value=\"\" class=\"inputText\"></a></td>";    in the browser

Comment: Updated my answer again, to show how you can show your line of code in its literal form in a browser.

Comment: You are welcome! Next time try to add more details about your problem. It was hard to understand what you actually wanted... I'll update my answer a last time, to show the actual solution